# xAct/xCoba and DSolve Don't Work Together

Tags: differential-equations, xact

**Context**

I'm trying to derive the Reissner-Nordstrom metric for a charged nonrotating black hole using xAct. The idea is to first have a metric of form

$$ds^2 = e^{2\alpha(r)}dt^2-e^{2\beta(r)}dr^2-r^2d\Omega^2$$

then to write the energy momentum tensor as $$T_{\mu\nu} = -F_{\mu\rho}F_\nu^\rho+g_{\mu\nu}F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}/4$$

Finally, write the Einstein Equations $G_{\mu\nu} = 8\pi T_{\mu\nu}$ and solve for $\alpha(r)$ and $\beta(r)$ using the differential equations you get.

Getting to the Einstein Equations was relatively straightforward, and I was able to get a system of differential equations.

[image: Einstein EQ]

Unfortunately, the problem is that $r$ in this case is represented by xAct by `r[]`, but Mathematica does not allow `DSolve` to work with differential equations where the independent variable (in this case, $r$, since we're trying to solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as functions of $r$) is itself a function. So In order to solve, I had to undefine *everything* and copy the equations and manipulate them that way.

[image]

I was then able to solve for the metric correctly, after an argument that $\alpha = -\beta$. The constant $c_1$ you see gives us the correct form when we force the metric to be the same as Schwarzchild for $Q=0$

[image]

**Questions**

I have two main questions:

(1) Is it possible to have xAct/xCoba work with DSolve directly, without having to undefine everything? Are there packages that work with xCoba that allow for these sorts of differential equation calculations for the metric? It's a bit annoying to have to undefine everything and copy/rewrite the expressions to not include these `r[]` terms, just to have Mathematica work with it well.

(2) (Less Important) I had a system of 4 differential equations - Certainly some of them are not independent of each other - for example the $\theta\theta$ and $\phi\phi$ components of the Einstein EQ are not independent. Is there any way I could've avoided the manual argument that $\alpha = -\beta$ and had Mathematica show me directly? If I try to put the 4 equations in, Mathematica's `DSolve` defaults to telling me the EQ are overdetermined. Trying to put any of the 2 equations in that seem independent, say with the $rr$ and $\theta\theta$ components doesn't have `DSolve` return anything. Is there any way I could've done this problem completely in Mathematica?

*I've put some of my code below - up to where I found the Einstein EQ.*

```
Needs["xAct`xCoba`"]
DefManifold[M, 4, {\[Lambda], \[Mu], \[Nu], \[Rho], \[Sigma], \[Gamma], \[Delta]}];
coords = {t[], r[], \[Theta][], \[Phi][]}; (*Define Manifold*)
DefScalarFunction[alpha, 
 PrintAs -> "\[Alpha]"]; DefScalarFunction[beta, 
 PrintAs -> "\[Beta]"]; (*Define Alpha and Beta Functions*)
DefChart[ch, M, {0, 1, 2, 3}, coords, ChartColor -> Blue];
gmatrix = DiagonalMatrix[{Exp[2*alpha[r[]]], -Exp[2*beta[r[]]], -(r[])^2, -r[]^2*(Sin[\[Theta][]])^2}];
g = CTensor[gmatrix, {-ch, -ch}]; (*Define Metric*)
SetCMetric[g, ch, SignatureOfMetric -> {1, 3, 0}];
CD = CovDOfMetric[g];
DefConstantSymbol[Q];
Fmatrix = {{0, -Q/(4 \[Pi]*r[]^2), 0, 0}, {Q/(4 \[Pi]*r[]^2), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}};
F = CTensor[Fmatrix, {-ch, -ch}]; (*Define Field Strength Tensor*)
Tmatrix = ComponentArray[-F[{-\[Mu], -ch}, {-\[Rho], -ch}]*F[{-\[Nu], -ch}, {\[Rho], ch}] + g[{-\[Mu], -ch}, {-\[Nu], -ch}]*F[{-\[Rho], -ch}, {-\[Sigma], -ch}]*F[{\[Rho], ch}, {\[Sigma], ch}]/4] // ContractBasis; (*Define Energy Momentum Tensor*)
T = CTensor[Tmatrix, {-ch, -ch}];
EinsteinEQ = {}; 
For[i = 0, i <= 3, i++, 
 AppendTo[EinsteinEQ, 
  FullSimplify[
    Einstein[CD][{i, -ch}, {i, -ch}] - 
     8*\[Pi]*GNewton*T[{i, -ch}, {i, -ch}]] == 0]] (*Build Einstein EQ*)
```

Comment: If you have no luck on this site, try here: https://groups.google.com/u/1/g/xact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DSolve[Take[EinsteinEQ, 2], {alpha, beta}, r[]]` works fine.  It does throw some errors but it still gives the correct result:

[image]

Alternately, you can use `DSolve[Take[EinsteinEQ, 2] /. {r[] -> r}, {alpha, beta}, r]`.  This replaces the "function with no argument" `r[]` with the "atomic symbol" `r`, which is more what `DSolve` is expecting.  Doing this which solves the equations without throwing any errors (except for the one about inverse functions, but I think that's unavoidable.)

As far as "which equations to use", note that I used the $tt$ and $rr$ components of the Einstein equation to solve this.  There is something of an art to knowing which equations to use when you have symmetries (such as time-invariance here) along with diffeomorphism invariance.  This would be off-topic here, but free to as a question over on [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) about this and I'll try to put together an answer on that site.